# Can not install MariaDB through Docker and Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, docker, mariadb, vagrantfile, dockerfile

When installing MariaDB through a Dockerfile and Vagrant I keep getting this error:

```
New password for the MariaDB "root" user:
Use of uninitialized value $_[1] in join or string at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/Stack.pm line 111.
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of stop.
Use of uninitialized value $val in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 83, <GEN6> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $val in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 84, <GEN6> line 1.
dpkg: error processing mariadb-server-10.0 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up libhtml-template-perl (2.91-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mariadb-server:
 mariadb-server depends on mariadb-server-10.0 (= 10.0.15+maria-1~wheezy); however:
  Package mariadb-server-10.0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing mariadb-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mariadb-server-10.0
 mariadb-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

This happens with every MariaDB that I have tried (10.0.15, 10.1.2).

My DockerFile:

```
# vim:set ft=dockerfile:
FROM debian:wheezy

# add our user and group first to make sure their IDs get assigned consistently, regardless of whatever dependencies get added
RUN groupadd -r mysql && useradd -r -g mysql mysql

# grab gosu for easy step-down from root
RUN gpg --keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys B42F6819007F00F88E364FD4036A9C25BF357DD4
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && curl -o /usr/local/bin/gosu -SL "https://github.com/tianon/gosu/releases/download/1.2/gosu-$(dpkg --print-architecture)" \
    && curl -o /usr/local/bin/gosu.asc -SL "https://github.com/tianon/gosu/releases/download/1.2/gosu-$(dpkg --print-architecture).asc" \
    && gpg --verify /usr/local/bin/gosu.asc \
    && rm /usr/local/bin/gosu.asc \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/gosu \
    && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove curl

RUN apt-key adv --keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 199369E5404BD5FC7D2FE43BCBCB082A1BB943DB

ENV MARIADB_MAJOR 10.0
ENV MARIADB_VERSION 10.0.15+maria-1~wheezy

RUN echo "deb http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/mariadb/repo/$MARIADB_MAJOR/debian wheezy main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mariadb.list

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
        mariadb-server=$MARIADB_VERSION \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/mysql \
    && mkdir /var/lib/mysql \
    && sed -ri 's/^(bind-address|skip-networking)/;\1/' /etc/mysql/my.cnf

VOLUME /var/lib/mysql

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /

ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]

EXPOSE 3306
CMD ["mysqld"]
```

I have been looking on Google after possible solutions but I could only find people having the same problem without any solution being posted.

My vagrant definition looks like this:

```
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    config.vm.define "mariadb" do |v|
        v.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
            d.build_dir = "./docker/mariadb"
            d.name = "mariadb"
            d.ports = ["3306:3306"]
            d.vagrant_vagrantfile = "#{DOCKER_HOST_VAGRANTFILE}"
            d.env = {
                MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "root",
                MYSQL_USER: "root",
                MYSQL_PASS: "root"
            }
        end
    end
end
```

Also, when I try to install MySQL instead of MariaDB then it works. So my idea here is that there is an error when setting the Root Passwords for MariaDB. The thing that makes me think that is that this error pops up just after the line `New password for the MariaDB "root" user:` and on the end it then says it hasn't been configured yet.

Maybe the problem is in the VagrantFile then? However I tried changing the way the env variables were set and that didn't fixed my problem :(

I would be glad if someone could help me with this.

Update:
DockerFile used: https://github.com/docker-library/mariadb/blob/d06c367c4b199f91b36f5f6fabf8305282b8abac/10.0/Dockerfile (I corrected the permissions to 755)

Comment: Can you post a link to the dockerfile you used to install MariaDB, as I see 203 on https://registry.hub.docker.com/search?q=mariadb&searchfield=

Comment: Instead of using vagrant, can you ssh to the MariaDB container ? I notice https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/5075

Comment: I added the DockerFile as asked, also I can not SSH to the container, even not when adding the d.has_ssh = true. This is probably because I can not even install it. Same problem shows up.

Comment: Do you have enough RAM ? http://serverfault.com/questions/642045/mariadb-10-0-docker-vagrant-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-co

Comment: I have 2Gb for the box so I should have more then enough yes

Comment: Ok it was the box that wasn't changed for the RAM, so now it is working :D Thanks :D :D

Comment: Also, you can add this to your dockerfile for unattended installation (no prompts, etc)

    ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

Comment: ok, thank you so much :D this solved my hours of headaches

Answer (score 1):

The solution was adding more RAM to my VirtualMachine and completely recreating it (so opening virtualbox and removing the boot2docker machine too). (Thanks to user2915097 for point this out!)